# sas loop over month from variable

Tags: loops, date, sas

I am tryinng to loop over a series of dates in order to create the dates inbetween. This is to be done in steps of month, always displaying the last day of the respective month. The start and end dates are given (first_date and last_date), while the last_date should always refer to the end of the previous month.

The original dataset looks like the following:

```
customer id   first_date  last_date 
xy       135  01.01.2000  25.03.2005 
xy       247  19.03.2003  25.03.2005 
ab       387  01.06.2010  30.12.2012 
ab       128  01.05.2010  28.02.2011 
...
```

My goal is to have a dataset which looks like this:

```
customer id   date
xy       135  31.01.2000
xy       135  28.02.2000
...
xy       135  28.02.2005
xy       247  31.03.2003
xy       247  30.04.2003
...
xy       247  28.02.2005
```

I found the solution to iterate over days quite straightforward (see below), but I am struggling to implement the monthly steps and the end of month dates.

```
data want;
set have;
by customer id;
do day = first_date to last_date;
output;
end;
format day date9.;
run;
```

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Good, detailed question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, lets get some data:

```
data have;
  attrib customer length=$10 informat=$10.
        id         informat=best.
        first_date informat=ddmmyy10. format=ddmmyy10.
        last_date  informat=ddmmyy10. format=ddmmyy10.
        ;

  input customer $
        id
        first_date
        last_date 
        ;

datalines;
xy       135  01.01.2000  25.03.2005 
xy       247  19.03.2003  25.03.2005 
ab       387  01.06.2010  30.12.2012 
ab       128  01.05.2010  28.02.2011 
;
run;
```

The `intnx()` function will come to the rescue here.  We are going to create a new variable called date, and then use the intnx function to return the end of the month for that date.  As long as that date is less than the end date, we will continue to output it to a dataset and then increment to the end of the following month.

```
data want;
  format date ddmmyy10.;

  set have;

  date = intnx('month',first_date,0,'end');
  do while (date le last_date);
    output;
    date = intnx('month',date,1,'end');
  end;

  drop first_date last_date;
run;
```

Comment: Good answer.  I find it slightly more intuitive (particularly for programmers used to traditional do x=y to z loops) to write it as, `date_start = intnx('month',first_date,0,'end');  do incr = 1 by 1 while (date le last_date);    output;    date =intnx('month',date_start,incr,'end');  end;`  You end up with the same result, it just makes it more intuitive to me.

Comment: Interesting - I've seen a few answers lately where people have used that style and I hadn't really seen it before.  Coming from a compsci background, I kind of just learnt the 3 basic C-style loops back in school (for, while, and do...while) and I just use the same structures for my loops in SAS.

Comment: Actually, this is a c style loop.  `for (incr=1; date le last_date; incr++)` would be the c equivalent.  SAS just organizes it a bit differently.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks a lot! I need to get more familiar with the intnx function!

Answer (score 1):

While I think Rob's answer is the right way to do this, it's probably helpful to see how to do it the way you were trying to.

Starting with this:

```
data want;
 set have;
 by customer id;
 do day = first_date to last_date;
  output;
 end;
 format day date9.;
run;
```

This gives you too many rows, right?  So what you need to do is identify where in the month you are.  There are a bunch of ways to do this.  Several date functions (like INTNX and INTCK) could be used to tell you where you are; but the easiest is just to compare `month(date)` with `month(date+1)`.  When they're different, you're on the last day of a month!

```
data want;
  set have;
  by customer id notsorted;
  do day = first_date to last_date;
    if month(day) ne month(day+1) then output;
  end;
  format day date9.;
run;
```

(I added `notsorted` since Rob's example data was not sorted, and I'm lazy. Probably not needed in your real case.)

I would note that this probably isn't your ideal solution - Rob's is probably that, in terms of data steps - in terms of speed.  This of course will iterate through every day rather than just once per month.

Answer (score 1):

Another option if you have the dataset you created above - with one row per day - is to use [`PROC EXPAND`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/60372/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_expand_sect001.htm), if you have the ETS module.  It's very handy for things like this.

```
data intermediate;
  set have;
  by customer id notsorted;
  do day = first_date to last_date;
    output;
  end;
  format day date9.;
run;;;
```

Here's your day-level data.  Then below is the PROC EXPAND statement, asking for monthly data, aligned at the end.  `id day;` identifies the time series variable, and `by customer id notsorted;` is the normal by statement (what variables identify the observations), with `notsorted` so they don't have to be in order relative to each other.

```
proc expand data=intermediate out=want from=day to=month align=end;
  id day;
  by customer id notsorted;
run;
```

This gives a slightly different solution than Rob's and my other solution, because it does give you the final row for each if it's not at the end of a month (and does set that final row *to* the end of the month).  If that's desired, great, and our solutions can easily be adapted to give that; if it's not desired, you'll have to remove it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple iterative `DO` loop by using the date interval functions. Subtract one from the number of intervals to make it end at the last day of the previous month.

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  do offset=0 to intck('month',first_date,last_date)-1;
    date=intnx('month',first_date,offset,'e');
    output;
  end;
  format date yymmdd10.;
run;
```

Comment: What if the last_date is actually the last day of a month?  (ie `last_date='31DEC2014'd;`)

Comment: @Joe - If the last date is the end of a month then my reading of the request is that they want to last date of the previous month.  So for `31DEC2014` the request as for `30NOV2014`.